# what is the significance and meaning of '?hjwqj'?

Tags: css

I am new to coding. I am really enjoying it. My question is that I coded a site and tried to upload it using filezilla (pics and in total 3 html pages in one folder, css file in a css folder along with other css files and same for js file being in a separate folder). I didn't know what to upload so I uploaded the whole css and js folders too since the html files had their path. web page showed 'index of/ and then below a list of all the files and folders. Then I put css and js file in the same folder as html files and adjusted their paths. Now the web page showed the results but no css designs working. I looked up and tried many things (hit and try). Eventually something worked but I would like to know the significance and the background knowledge behind it. The piece of code I added was '?hjwqj' after my css extension and that made my css load. Could someone kindly explain what this is please? Also when do I need to use it and when not please?

Comment: The browser thinks it's a new file since the name changed, so that busts a user's cache of the file and forces them to download a new version of the file.

Comment: sorry.. very new to web developing so pardon my lack of knowledge. All the help is much appreciated. I would like to know why adding these certain letters (?hjwqj). I have looked further on here that at times people put a css version at the end for some reason (until now I thought css3 is a version but seeing how people add ?v3.2....  or other digits) has already made me question my knowledge of how many css versions are out there. Even then it kinda hints about itself a little where it starts from ?v.. (v for version i guess), i only request to explain why ?hjwqj.  thanks in advance